# Question about SharePoint Search Not Displaying Results

Tags: sharepoint-search

Search results are showing up blank "Nothing here matches your search." I just ran a full crawl that took 3.5 hours, and it shows it crawled 200,000 entries.

This is a 2016 on 2 servers. our 2nd server is our search/application server.
I've dug through Google which has many different suggestions. Here is what I've tried:

1. Completely rebuilt the SSA using the GUI method (first try was
   through PowerShell)
2. Edited the Content Sources to crawl server name
   URL
3. adding our SSL cert to the trusted store in CA

I'm going to start a new Web App and see if SharePoint will crawl through it, but are there any other suggestions I can try while I work this out. Appreciate the help!

Comment: New Web app and site collection didn't change anything :(

Comment: If you are certain that the items were successfully crawled then you need to look at permissions. Is the crawl account only a READER on the web applications. Does the query account have access to the content?

Answer (score 1):

Content sources shouldn't be pointed to the SSL based web application. search has be always on default web app and it should work fine so you need to extend the web application if you need to use SSL's so those can be used by the resular users but the default can be dedicated to the search

Comment: You can use SSL on the default zone. You are correct about only crawling the default zone.